# How can I select a certain string in txt file and list it in csv file?

Tags: python, csv, text-files, export-to-csv

**Here is my content in my text file: and I only want to get this sha1 and description then parse it to a csv file using prefix and delimiter a trimed the strings then selected the sha1 between "\" and "->" then I want to get the description.**

```
         +----------------------------------------------------+
         |          VSCAN32            Ver 2.00-1655          |
         |                                                    |
         |     Copyright (c) 1990 - 2012 xxx xxx xxx Inc.     |
         |                                                    |
         |    Maintained by xxxxxxxxx  QA for VSAPI Testing   |
         +----------------------------------------------------+

Setting Process Priority to NORMAL: Success 1

Successfully setting POL Flag to 0
VSGetVirusPatternInformation is invoked
Reading virus pattern from lpt$vpn.527 (2018/09/25) (1452700)


Scanning samples_extracted\88330686ae94a9b97e1d4f5d4cbc010933f90f9a->(MS Office 2007 Word 4045-1)
->Found Virus [TROJ_FRS.VSN11I18]



Scanning samples_extracted\8d286d610f26f368e7a18d82a21dd68b68935d6d->(Microsoft RTF 6008-0)
->Found Virus [Possible_SMCCVE20170199]



Scanning samples_extracted\a10e5f964eea1036d8ec50810f1d87a794e2ae8c->(ASCII text 18-0)
->Found Virus [Trojan.VBS.NYMAIM.AA]


18 files have been checked.
 Found 16 files containing viruses.
(malloc count, malloc total, free total) = (0, 35, 35)
```

**So far this is my code: it still outputs many string but i only need the sha1 and description to be parsed in csv I used split so the sha1 can be selected between "\" and "->" it does put the sha1 but the description is not trimed, and the contents are still there**

```
import csv

INPUTFILE = 'input.txt'
OUTPUTFILE = 'output.csv'
PREFIX = '\\'
DELIMITER = '->'

def read_text_file(inputfile):
    data = []
    with open(inputfile, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        if not line == '':
            line = line.split(PREFIX, 1)[-1]
            parts = line.split(DELIMITER)
            data.append(parts)

    return data

def write_csv_file(data, outputfile):
    with open(outputfile, 'wb') as csvfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"',
                                quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        for row in data:
            csvwriter.writerow(row)

def main():
    data = read_text_file(INPUTFILE)
    write_csv_file(data, OUTPUTFILE)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Here is what I want in my csv: sha1 and description, but my output file dispplays the whole text file, but it filtered the sha1 and putted it in a column**
[image: sha1 and description only]

**EDIT: At first it was working but this line of text can be placed in the csv file because of it's multiple lines, any answer please?**

```
Scanning samples_extracted\0191a23ee122bdb0c69008971e365ec530bf03f5
 - Invoice_No_94497.doc->Found Virus [Trojan.4FEC5F36]->(MIME 6010-0)

 - Found 1/3 Viruses in samples_extracted\0191a23ee122bdb0c69008971e365ec530bf03f5
```

Comment: A little problem with your question is that lacks a bit of focus. The description you give is 'here is what is happening, but also that is happening, and I also want another thing to happen', it is hard to see what is wrong. You can probably narrow down your question by throwing away the file read / file write operations and a sceeenshot. Try refactoring your code into something like `doc = """" file contents or string """; result = parse(doc)` and assert about `result`. This way it will be much closer to your actual problem and will make your question more helpable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the minimum changes - you can use this part of code:

```
for line in lines:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    if not line == '' and DELIMITER in line and not "Found" in line: # <---
        line = line.split(PREFIX, 1)[-1]
        parts = line.split(DELIMITER)
```

But I would prefer to use regex:

```
import re

for line in lines:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    if re.search(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]{40}->\(', line): # <----
        line = line.split(PREFIX, 1)[-1]
        parts = line.split(DELIMITER)
        data.append(parts)
```

The result will be:

```
cat output.csv
"88330686ae94a9b97e1d4f5d4cbc010933f90f9a","(MS Office 2007 Word 4045-1)"
"8d286d610f26f368e7a18d82a21dd68b68935d6d","(Microsoft RTF 6008-0)"
"a10e5f964eea1036d8ec50810f1d87a794e2ae8c","(ASCII text 18-0)"
```

Comment: it's working for some text but it doesn't do the function for multiple line, please refer to my EDITED question

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import pandas as pd
a=open("inputfile","a+")
storedvalue=[]
for text in a.readlines():
    matched_words=(re.search(r'\d.+?->\(.*?\)',text))
    if matched_words!=None:
        matched_words=matched_words.group()
        matched_words=matched_words.split("->")
        storedvalue.append(tuple(matched_words))
dataframe=pd.DataFrame(storedvalue,columns=["hashvalue","description"])
dataframe.to_csv("output.csv")
```

The result will be:

```
hashvalue                                     description
88330686ae94a9b97e1d4f5d4cbc010933f90f9a    (MS Office 2007 Word 4045-1)
8d286d610f26f368e7a18d82a21dd68b68935d6d    (Microsoft RTF 6008-0)
10e5f964eea1036d8ec50810f1d87a794e2ae8c     (ASCII text 18-0)
```

Comment: ImportError: No module named pandas

Comment: @jeremydevera try to install pandas by using this command pip install pandas on your command prompt